# cocos2d modal window with CCLayer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, modal-dialog

Trying to implement a modal window with CCLayer. My modal view layer is added as a child of another layer.

On my modal view layer I've added methods(the touch is enabled):

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}
```

Why the modal view layer it doesn't swallos my touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set priority to -129. Menu have lowest priority (kCCMenuTouchPriority = -128). Just try this code:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-129 swallowsTouches:YES];
```